# MATLAB export multiple .csv files at one time

Tags: matlab, matrix, csv

I have a matrix where I need to export each column into a separate .csv file. 
I know the number of columns and I can achieve my desired result if I specifically select one column to export. I would do this by:

```
dlmwrite('1.csv',data(:,1), 'precision', 9)
```

Therefore if I want column 2 I would change the variable to data`(:,2)` and save this as `2.csv`.

So I want a loop that will do all this automatically. I have tried

```
for i=1:Number_of_Columns
    dlmwrite('(i).csv',csv_data(:,(i)), 'precision', 9)
end
```

which clearly won't work but I am unsure how to do it.

Any help or advice would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the filename. If you put `i` between quotes it will be taken as character instead of a variable. (In your case your filename will always be "(i).csv")

You can concatenate strings using [ ], and since i is an integer you have to convert it to string using `num2str()`

Try:

```
for i=1:Number_of_Columns
    dlmwrite([num2str(i) '.csv'], csv_data(:,i), 'precision', 9)
end
```

PD: Since you are storing each column (not each row) in a file, I'm not sure if you want a file where each element is in a separate line, or if you want the column to be stored as a row and separated by commas.

If you want the latter, transpose your column:

```
dlmwrite([num2str(i) '.csv'], csv_data(:,i).', 'precision', 9)
```

Note that the transpose operator is `.'` instead of the complex conjugate `'` (this is a common misuse since the results are the same as long as you only use real numbers)